# How to fix too sensitive key on a laptop? Workaround using Autohotkey?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, laptop-repair, repair

Keyboard of my good old Dell Latitude D530 is very old and different keys start to be broken... the <kbd>]</kbd> key close to <kbd>Enter</kbd> became super sensitive - it triggers even when I touch it only very very slightly... So it triggers every time I just move my fingers around, which is very annoying. Don't know what to do about this, I tried to clean everything under the key but it didn't help.

So, I though, would it be possible to write an Autohotkey script such that the key would trigger only if held for certain (pre-defined) time?

Comment: These keyboard go bad real quick from personal experience. Any real reason why you can't buy a new keyboard? They are less than 20$ USD on ebay from china. You can also use a USB keyboard and disable the old one meanwhile.

Comment: @NatsuKage new keyboard for old Dell Latitude D530? They are still selling it? :-o

Comment: Yes. Of course not from Dell directly though. This was a popular laptop, so many parts are available. ex: https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-laptop-keyboard-for-Dell-Latitude-D520-D530-BLACK/153334889802?hash=item23b378bd4a:g:x-AAAOSwu3tcNyi9

Comment: Yep, new keyboard is best solution.

Comment: thanks guys. But anyway, **some temporary solution would come in handy. What about the Autohotkey script?**

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable on Autohotkey, which is why I'm not giving an answer yet. The next simplest method to prevent the ] key from activating: remove the plastic key from the keyboard?

Comment: @NatsuKage 1) "of course not from Dell directly" - because of the price? And the 3rd party keyboards are 100% compatible? 2) but I need to use the key :-D

Comment: The keyboard written New are often new old stock (NOS). Dell simply doesn't manufacture them anymore. And I'm just saying to remove the plastic key (carefully!). Under the plastic key is a rubber membrane.You can still use the key by pressing this membrane which should be as sensitive. It's possible there's something stuck underneath as well, making it so sensitive.

Comment: HW fix: insert some plastic closed-cell foam under the key with a tweezer. This also helps me with tactile feedback so that I don't accidentally depress Caps Lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the ] key for more than 0.2 seconds to send it:

```
$]::                   ; the dollar prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used
    KeyWait, ], T0.2  ; wait 0.2 seconds for ] to be released
    If (!ErrorLevel)  ; if the command isn't timed out 
        return        ; do nothing
    Send ]            ; otherwise send the key 
return
```